# Elements in array aren't changing value

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

My function is intended to capitalize the first letter of each word but after the for loop runs the array is unchanged. What am I missing?

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  var splitStr = str.split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    var word = splitStr[i];
    word = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
  }
  return splitStr.join(' ');
}

console.log(capitalize('my test'));
```

Comment: splitStr[i].toUpperCase should fix it, you do not need the word variable.

Comment: The issue is that you are calling a new variable in your loop and then not doing anything to it. Assigning word to `splitStr[i]` and then changing the var `word` won't change `splitStr[i]`

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `word =` with `splitStr[i]` and you're done

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  var splitStr = str.split(' ');
   
  for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    var word = splitStr[i];
    splitStr[i] = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
  }
  return splitStr.join(' ');
}

console.log(capitalize("this is it"));
```

Reason: because you're not updating it in original string `splitStr`. `toUpperCase` does not modify the original element but returns the updated value, so you need to assign it back to that particular string index to modify.

Answer (score 2):

Assign back value to array itself

Here's working solution -

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  var splitStr = str.split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    var word = splitStr[i];
    splitStr[i] = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
  }
  return splitStr.join(' ');
}

console.log(capitalize("stack over flow"));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing this

```
var word = splitStr[i];
```

You are not getting a reference to the index so when you update word, it is not updating the index of the array.

```
splitStr[i] = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the value of the array by setting the array of index i to equal some value, not the other way around.

```
   function capitalize(str) {
   var splitStr = str.split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
  var word = splitStr[i];
 splitStr[i] = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
  }
 return splitStr.join(' ');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking a reference to each word, you need to actually change it. An option is to reassign using `map`:

```
let str = 'hi i am jack'

str = arr.split(' ').map(word => `${word[0].toUpperCase()}${word.slice(1)}`).join(' ');

console.log(str) // 'Hi I Am Jack'
```

Comment: Please provide explanation to your code to make for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
`var word = splitStr[i];
 word = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);`
```

should be following to modify original string

```
`var word = splitStr[i];
 splitStr[i] = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);`
```

I had gone further and removed intermediate `word` variable

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  var splitStr = str.split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    splitStr[i] = splitStr[i][0].toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].slice(1);
  }
  return splitStr.join(' ');
}

console.log(capitalize("Hello, i am here"));
```